# Shopify Updating Inventory 400 Bad Request

Tags: xml, shopify

I have a simple item in Shopify that I want to update with XML. Here is what I am sending to Shopify:

```
<product>
  <id type="integer">6620419777</id>
  <title>Test</title>
  <inventory-management>shopify</inventory-management>
  <inventory-quantity type="integer">4</inventory-quantity>
</product>
```

I get back "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inventory qty belongs to the product variant. Even products that don't have variants actually have one variant, it's just not visible in the admin.

Relevant documentation: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product_variant